# compute minimum sum of pairs distances between 2 groups of dots

Tags: algorithm

assume we have 2 groups of dots(n red dots and n blue dots). now we want to connect exactly one of blues to exactly one of reds that the sum of connections lines become minimum. Is there any none brute-force suggestion?

thanks in advance

Comment: That means `n` connection lines minimum? It's unclear what your precise problem is.

Comment: @Evert yes, there would be n connection lines. we want to minimize the sum of lengths of the lines

Comment: This is called min-weight perfect matching